# What are the best troops to have in your Clan Castle in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Best defensive troops to have in your clan castle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally recommend (in this order:) Dragons, Wizards or Witches, or Minions. Dragon is first because of the fact that it does A LOT of AREA damage, which is great. Wizards are second because they do area damage but are not flying units and can therefore be attacked by more troops. Witches are also great, especially because they can keep summoning minions for a long time and are a great distraction and can stay alive for quite some time. Minions are third because while they can fly, they do not deal as much damage as a dragon or wizards.